# Remove trailing 0 in a server response to use JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have the following PHP code to try and send back a JSON response:

```
$response = array(
        "result"        => true,
        "text"          => "Here is some text"
);
echo json_encode($response);
```

I try and parse this in jQuery by using the following code:

```
var dataArray = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
console.log(dataArray);
```

When I check the console I get an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`. When I look at what is returned in the response to the console here are the results:

```
{"result":true,"text":"Here is some text"}0
```

Is it because the system is adding a trailing 0? If so, how can I remove it so that I can read the JSON response correctly?

Comment: Most likely, you echo something else after this. Remove that.

Comment: Find the code (debugging leftovers?) that generates the zero and remove it.

Comment: The trailing 0 is not a normal behaviour. Are you sure you don't output anything after calling `json_encode`?

Comment: try calling `exit;` right after the echo. The real solution though is find where the extra output is coming from

Comment: @charlietfl This is only a debugging measure. The code generating the `0` is still out there and could likely get called again.

Comment: @snwflk isn't that pretty much what i said

Comment: @charlietfl I wasn't aware of the changes to your comment. Yes, that's exactly what your comment states.

Comment: @charlietfl It's in wordpress and if I don't add exit after my function wordpress adds the trailing zero.